# Vs Code file saving is too slow

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After I format my windows11 Labtop by window, I found my VsCode file saving is too slow.
(Python files, and clone of my github-repos)

It is only slow when I tried to save file. No matter with make new file, or delete, etc.

I found many questions of this, so I found what my extension takes so much time. so I checked that my vscode git extensions have some issues.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiYJt.png)

My VsCode version is up-to-date, and my git is up-to-date too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vePd6.png)

Should I don't use my VsCode's git extension? Please give me other choices.